# What's wrong with these columns?

Tags: mysql

is there something that I'm missing? Thanks :)

Error

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `venues` 
ADD `IF_AIRCONDITIONING` BOOLEAN( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
, ADD `IF_LIVE_MUSIC` BOOLEAN( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
, ADD `IF_TABLE_FOOTBALL` BOOLEAN( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
     '(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  ADD `IF_LIVE_MUSIC` BOOLEAN(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', ' at line 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the quotes around 0 in `DEFAULT '0'`, or use `FALSE` or `false` (also without quotes)

Also you shouldn't have to specify a length for boolean fields, try getting rid of `( 1 )`

Comment: Thank you, however I am using the phpmyadmin gui to create the columns, not an sql syntax.

Comment: Ok, but why not just create the fields in the command line interface? After all you only have to create them once.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was, indeed that a boolean does not need to have a length specified :)

Comment: No PM system so using this.. [nice effort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10293926/447356) editing his grammar but that person looks like doing it on purpose so he just deleted the answer altogether. As the answer does contain valuable information I voted to undelete, can you do the same?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: Sorry for that.. let's hope he learned the lesson though (wishful thinking?)